# waiting for approval tab does not show disable users in Kentico 10

Tags: kentico

I've checked this option in settings that says: "Registration requires administrator's approval:" in kentico10.

[image]

and in my custom registration web part I've unchecked Enable user after registration.

[image]

but I can't see unable users waiting for the approval tab.

[image]

as below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you checked the setting **Registration requires email confirmation** in **Settings -> Security and membership**

you need to unchecked this. since it's checked, system will send email to user after registration. while your email configuration has a problem, user can not received the confirmation link and it wont be worked.